# Mobile phones in luggage at Heathrow

Tags: uk, luggage, airport-security

I'm going to the Philippines from Heathrow UK and as all Filipinos when we go home  we always buy stuff for our families back home. I was thinking to have with me in my hand carry four mobile phones wrapped with bubble wraps all turned off. Would I be able to do this without being stopped at security?

Comment: It's not security's job to police what you export. Provided you can show that four phones aren't dangerous you should be fine. Customs in the Philippines might be more of an issue.

Comment: @ReddHerring Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: So i dont need to make sure they are all charged and fully working to the security officers at heathrow? Planning not to charged them and keep them off and in boxes whilst o go through security??

Answer (score 3):

Heathrow Security is discussed on [this Heathrow Airport webpage](https://www.heathrow.com/departures/security-and-baggage). That page contains this admonition:

**Electronic devices**

*Make sure your electronic devices are charged. If they don't switch on, you may not be allowed to take them on to the aircraft.
Charging points are available throughout the airport and a free charging service is provided in Dixons Travel stores.*